# How can i create and run Jar file from spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, jar, spring-batch

I have a **spring batch** application which contains **two job**, the application in **eclipse work correctly** but when i create jar and run it, not working i need execute it using **CommandLineJobRunner**.

I try create a jar using severeal ways:

---

I using the maven comand **mvn clean install** and **mvn clean package**, in this case if I run the jar using ->

**java -jar**  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner    the jar always execute all jobs.

in other case if i try it using **java -cp** i get:

*Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner*

---

**Using ecilpse to export jar file**

In eclipse export -> jar -> runneableJar, in this case:

if i use **java -cp** i get FileNotFoundException application.properties, but this file is in resources.

if i use **java -jar** i get *no main manifest attribute.*

In eclipse export -> jar -> Jar file, in this case:

if i use **java -cp** i get -> *Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner*

if i use **java -jar** i get *no main manifest attribute.*

I don't know what to try. 
thancks and sorry for my english, is not my native languaje

Comment: I execute the jar using java -jar or java -cp <jarFile> org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner <JavaconfigClass> <JobName> <JobParameters>

Comment: Seems 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner' is not getting packaged inside the jar. Please share the POM file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least three options:

- Add spring batch and all other dependencies in your classpath
- Use the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to shade all your dependencies in the same jar
- Use Spring Boot and it will do it for you automatically, see example in the [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/).

Comment: Hi  i have seen that guide and in my case not working, using these jar always try to execute all jobs.  How is the pom.xml configuration with maven shade plugin, currently i have all jars in the BOOT-INF\lib folder but the jar not work.

Comment: I see my manfest, Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: myClass, i change Start-class  to Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner and naw i get java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JobLauncher must be provided.  Please add one to the configuration. any idea?

Answer (score -1):

it works now, the problem was the plugin, as Mahmoud said, was necessary use the maven plugin but on other hand i had the db2 dependency with scope provided, Maven dependency scope provided is used during build and test the project. They are also required to run, but should not exported, because the dependency will be provided by the runtime, for instance, by servlet container or application server.